# How to get city value from checkout on change

Tags: magento2

I want to get city name which is in drop down once the city name changed on checkout page.How i can get city name when user change city name on checkout before placing order.

Comment: I get confused, could you confirm again that you have a city-dropdown instead of state? As far as I know Magento doesn't have city as dropdown

Comment: Yes i had added city drop down functionality.Now i need to get that city valu in my custom module once user just change city from dropdown.

Comment: You can check my answer here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/332649/method-which-triggers-after-change-in-shipping-address/332656#332656

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code:

```
require(['jquery',], function($) {
    var loadCityField = setInterval(function(){
        if($(document).find("input[name='city']").length > 0) {
            clearInterval(loadCityField);
            $(document).find("input[name='city']").on('change', function() {
                console.log($(this).val());
            });     
        }
    }, 100);
});
```